# Vue 3 update:modelValue only work with npm run dev (vite) and not working with npm run serve (vite preview)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite

I have a project with Vue 3 `"^3.2.41"` and Vite `"^4.2.1"` and i create Input.vue components to use at parent components.

My Input.vue component code is like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="mb-6">
        <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-grey-darker text-xs font-bold mb-2" :for="id">
            {{ label }} <span class="text-red-600" v-if="isRequired">*</span>
        </label>
        <input :id="id" v-model="modelValue" @input="emit('update:modelValue', modelValue)" :class="inputClasses" :type="type"
            :placeholder="placeholder">
        <ValidationMessage :validation="validation" :field="id" />
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import ValidationMessage from '@/components/ValidationMessage.vue'

defineProps({
    isRequired: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    label: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    id: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    modelValue: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    type: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    placeholder: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
    },
    validation: {
        type: Object,
        default: null,
    },
    inputClasses: {
        type: String,
        default: 'appearance-none block w-full bg-grey-lighter text-grey-darker border border-red rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3',
    },
})

const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
</script>
```

and i use that Input.vue at parent component Create.vue:

```
<template>
    <loading v-if="course.loading" />
    <div class="pt-15">
        <div class="grid gap-6 mb-8">
            <div class="min-w-0 p-4 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-xs dark:bg-gray-800">
                <h4 class="mb-4 font-semibold text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-300">
                    Add data
                </h4>

                <form @submit.prevent="store">
                    <Input isRequired label="Judul" id="title" v-model="course.fields.title" type="text"
                        placeholder="Masukkan judul" :validation="validation" />
                    <BtnSubmit title="Simpan" />
                    <BtnCancel router-name="admin.courses.index" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'
import Loading from '@/components/Loading.vue'

import Input from '@/components/Form/Input.vue'

import BtnSubmit from '@/components/Button/BtnSubmit.vue'
import BtnCancel from '@/components/Button/BtnCancel.vue'

import { useStore } from '@/stores'

const { course } = useStore()

const router = useRouter()

let validation = ref([])

onMounted(async () => {
    course.resetFields()
})

const store = async () => {
    try {
        await course.createCourse(router)
    } catch (error) {
        validation.value = error
    }
}
</script>
```

I very confused when i run `npm run dev` its working perfectly, but when i run `npm run build` and try to `npm run serve` its error:

```
Input-00fb8882.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: modelValue is not defined
    at i.onUpdate:modelValue.t.<computed>.t.<computed> [as _assign] (Input-00fb8882.js:1:969)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (index-83e87120.js:1:63876)
```

My package.json code:

```
{
  "name": "learn-vue",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "serve": "vite preview",
    "build-dev": "vite build --mode development",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "vite lint"
  },
---other depedencies---
```

How to fix this problem? Thanks before

Comment: I'm not sure if this can fix the error because it's obscure, but 1) the use of <input> inside a comp of the same name is ambiguous and could result in a recursion (unlikely to happen with script setup syntax) 2) `v-model="modelValue" @input="emit('update:modelValue', modelValue)"` is wrong because this will modify a prop, which is readonly, should be `:modelValue="modelValue" @input="emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"`

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks its now working with ```:value="modelValue" @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"```. But i have still have problem with other component, i use Editor tinyMce, and do the same syntax to my Editor.vue code: ```<Editor :id="id" :value="modelValue" :api-key="apiKey" @change="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)" :init="editorInit" />``` its return ```undefined```

Comment: Check how v-model works, there's no target.value in comps https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `<input>` inside a component of the same name is ambiguous and could result in a recursion. It's unlikely to happen with `script setup` syntax but is better to avoid because this part is not explicitly documented.

`v-model="modelValue"` is wrong because this will modify a prop which is readonly.

A pass-through wrapper needs to desugar `v-model`:

```
<input :modelValue="modelValue" @input="emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)">
```

It depends on a component what input and output values are, but generally there will be no `target` because it's primarily specific to native events, so it will be:

```
<Editor :value="modelValue" @change="$emit('update:modelValue', $event)">
```

Comment: Thanks, i have to try write ```<Editor :value="modelValue" @change="$emit('update:modelValue', $event)">``` but the value is return object, when i try to ```$event.target.value``` its return undefined

Comment: It's specific to the component in use, it's not listed in the question, its usage to be reflected in its documentation. That it uses `value` and not `modelValue` prop already means that it doesn't fit v-model convention

Comment: thanks, its work now with ```:value="modelValue" :api-key="apiKey" @change="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.level.content)"```